# How to catch an asynchronous error in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, error-handling

Is there a way to ignore asynchronous errors while calling a function?

#### Synchronous

```js
function synchronous() {
    console.log('Nice feature');
    throw new Error('Async Error');
}

try {
    synchronous();
    console.log('Succeeded');
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Caught');
}
```

Console Output:
`Nice feature`
`Caught`

#### Asynchronous

```js
async function asynchronous() {
    console.log('Nice feature');
    throw new Error('Async Error');
}

try {
    asynchronous();
    console.log('Succeeded');
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Caught');
}
```

Console Output:
`Nice feature`
`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Async Error at asyncFunc`

Comment: You should learn about `await`, `Promise.prototype.catch`, and optionally global error handlers, which catch everything you otherwise forgot to catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two options:

```
(async () => {
  try {
    await asynchronous();
    console.log('Succeeded');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Caught');
  }
});
```

or

```
 asynchronous()
       .then(r => {
         console.log('succeeded');
       })
       .catch(e => {
           console.log('caught');
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that answers your question, but if "await" for the result of calling asynchronous() function, the error will not occur